# c# enum constants map to unique integer values

Tags: c#, enums

is there any way in c# to ensure enum constants map to unique integer values.

```
public enum Color
{
None =0,
red = 1,
blue= 2,
white = 3
}
```

Here  if i do change numeric value of "white from 3 to 2" i should get the compilation error.

In my project i'm saving the enum integer value in DB respect to constant.
i need a constraint in enum like if someone add a new constant in enum( e.g black). user must provide the unique numeric value with enum constant.

thanks

Comment: Can you just omit the explicit value specification and let the compiler determine them?

Comment: Also, are you using C# 4.0 or later? If so, you can take advantage of [code contracts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/11/11/introduction-to-code-contracts-melitta-andersen.aspx) to simulate compile-time static asserts.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be not to explicitly set the values in the `enum` definition. Put a comment in the `enum` definition telling anyone adding to it to ensure they only add to the end.

For example:

```
public enum Color
{
    None,
    red,
    blue,
    white,
    // **NEW ENTRIES MUST ONLY BE ADDED AT THE END OF THE ENUM**
}
```

Alternatively use the built-in `Color` structure and its `ToArgb( )` method. Or indeed the [`KnownColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: I would explicitely set the values _and_ also add your comment. Just in case... ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim: Just in case of what? The compiler stops working properly? :)

Comment: In case someone still inserts in between, so that at least my database values are still valid. Imagine an enum that contains more than one screen height of entries; one might not see the hint at the bottom. To avoid inserting a hint at the top, too, I would (and do) prefer writing the integer values explicitely.

Comment: yes, i would prefer to assign integer value explicitly, i have the same question in my mind what Uwe Keim just asked. because enum has more than 100 values right now and it will increase for sure..

Comment: Another solution ( at runtime ) would be to use reflection to iterate through the `enum` constants and ensure that they are unique. This could be done at startup and bomb out if there were any duplicates.